# Simplifying $f(\sqrt{7})$, where $f(x) = \sqrt{x-4\sqrt{x-4}}+\sqrt{x+4\sqrt{x-4}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, complex-numbers, nested-radicals, rationalising-denominator

> If $f(x) = \sqrt{x-4\sqrt{x-4}}+\sqrt{x+4\sqrt{x-4}}$ ; then $f(\sqrt {7})=\; ?$

I tried solving this equation through many methods, I tried rationalizing, squaring, etc. But after each of them, the method became really lengthy and ugly.

I also noted that once we substitute $\sqrt {7}$ the inner part of the radical becomes imaginary. How to proceed with this piece of information?

Please help me with this problem. Any more innovative methods would be appreciated.

---

Answer: $4$.

---

Edit $[7^{th}$ March, $2021]$:

I was told yesterday that this question was wrong and that we were supposed to find $f(2\sqrt5)$. Although I can solve with $2\sqrt5$ the same way as given below in the answers.... What I don't understand is that why $\sqrt7$ doesn't work. Can someone please help?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Which square roots do you have in mind?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think the OP means $\sqrt{\sqrt{7}-4}$ is imaginary

Comment: Maybe, after some squaring and rearranging iterations, find a polynomial with integer coefficients that satisfies one (and hence all) interpretations of the square roots, and then the rational root theorem might provide one or more rational values possibility to investigate (or rational values of its square, if you get a polynomial in $x^2).$

Comment: That is clear to me. But $\sqrt{\sqrt 7-4}$ means $i\sqrt{4-\sqrt7}$? Or does it mean $-i\sqrt{4-\sqrt7}$? And, after that, *which* square root is $\sqrt{\sqrt7\pm\sqrt{\sqrt7-4}}$?

Comment: $f(x)=4$ when $x\leq 8$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your latest edit, if a complex number $x$ is not nonnegative real, there are two cases with regard to its square root:

1. $x<0$. In this case what I have learned is $\sqrt x=\sqrt{-x} i$. Maybe some math textbooks will consider this illegal but many authors comfortably regard $\sqrt{-1}$ as $i$.
2. $x=a+bi$ where $b\ne0$. In this case there are two numbers whose square equal to $x$ and one should avoid writing $\sqrt x$.

If $x=\sqrt 7$, it is ok to ask: find all complex numbers $z$ such that $z^2=\sqrt7 - 4\sqrt {\sqrt 7 - 4}$. It's also ok to ask you to find all complex numbers $z$ such that $z^2=\sqrt 7 + 4\sqrt {\sqrt 7 -4}$. Each will have two solutions (one being the opposite of the other). If you add the two (separate) solutions with positive real part you will get $4$. If you add the two solutions with negative real part you will get $-4$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $\sqrt{x-4}=u \to x=u^2+4\\$so
$$\sqrt{x-4\sqrt{x-4}}+\sqrt{x+4\sqrt{x-4}}=\\ \sqrt{u^2+4-4u}+\sqrt{u^2+4+4u}=\\
|u-2|+|u+2|=\\
|\sqrt{x-4}-2|+|\sqrt{x-4}+2|$$ but when deals to imaginary numbers absolute sign is not necessary.

Comment: The square root of a square is not equal to the absolute value when the argument is not real.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = 4 g(t)$, $x = 4(t^2+1)$. Then, provided that $\Re t \notin\{ 1, -1\}$,

$$\begin{split}
  g(t) &= \tfrac{1}{2}\left(
    \sqrt{(1-t)^2}+\sqrt{(1+t)^2}\right) \\
    &= \begin{cases}
    -t & \Re t < -1 \\
    1 & -1 < \Re t < 1 \\
    t & \Re t > 1
    \end{cases}\text{.}
\end{split}$$

That expression is found by the complex-number identity

$$\sqrt{a^2}=\begin{cases}
  a & \Re a > 0 \\
  -a & \Re a < 0
\end{cases}\text{,}$$
and the constraint on the domain comes from ignoring the branch cut. Then when $x=\sqrt{7}$, $t=\pm \mathrm{i}\sqrt{1-\tfrac{\sqrt{7}}{4}}$, so $g(t)=1$ and $f(x)=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the denesting formula

$$\sqrt{a\pm\sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}} \pm \sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}$$
We have
$$f(x) = \sqrt{x-4\sqrt{x-4}}+\sqrt{x+4\sqrt{x-4}} \\= 2\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-16(x-4)}}{2}}=2\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{(8-x)^2}}{2}}$$

Now $\sqrt7<8$, therefore
$$f(\sqrt 7)=2\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 7+8- \sqrt 7}{2}}=2\cdot 2=4.$$

However as one of the members pointed out, the square root of a nonreal complex number is not well defined. We may get around this by requiring that the "square root" have nonnegative real part, but this is not standard practice.

**Update:** You can just square both sides directly:

$$(f(x))^2=2x+2\sqrt{x^2-(4-x)^2} = 2x+2\sqrt{(8-x)^2}$$
So if $x\leq 8$ then $f(x)=\sqrt{2x+2(8-x)}=4.$